# Is there an easy way to SELECT FROM another session's temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporary-tables

Is there an easy way to select the data from another session's temp table? I need to do so ad-hocly to debug an issue that I have limited visibility on otherwise.
E.g. if I have access to TEMPDB, is it possible to access the table object itself?

I saw this post from Paul White on one way to do it, but it's a lot more involved then I was hoping for: [Viewing Another Session's Temporary Table](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/viewing-another-session-s-temporary-table.html)

I cannot switch the code to use a global temp table for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#temp` is session scope

[CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) - Temporary Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables)

A local temporary table, #table_name, exists only for the duration of a user session or the procedure that created the temporary table.

Do the official microsoft way no tricks, it would end in a mess

Comment: I'm definitely not looking to use in production code, but rather something I can easily use to debug a specific issue in a specific edge case I'm in. It'll likely be a one time use.

Comment: Knowing a one-off trick would be great. As in my case, I'm running an Audt query that is taking days and can't check the progress as just before the job started, I forgot to add the ## in the temp table name and just realized after 3 days. And now I can't check the progress from another session without stopping the progress or will miss the deadline :(